# Can I install Ubuntu on a 3.5GB mini PC?

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements

I want to install Ubuntu on a mini PC which has only 3.5GB disk space. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lubuntu 13.10 has a minimal desktop environment that is suitable for low-end hardware like your mini PC, however even Lubuntu requires at least 4.7GB of available disk space for best results.

[image]

#### Instructions for installing Lubuntu 13.10 and later on the mini PC

1. Boot the Lubuntu live USB.
2. Open a terminal. Type `sudo -i leafpad /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py`. Click on *Options* and select line number. At about line #853 will be something like "min_disk size = size x 2 #fudge factor", change 2 to 1.4 and then save.
3. Run the Install Lubuntu. It should now say minimum disk size 3GB. Just be sure when you get to the disk partition/install part select *Other* and set up the drive as one ext4 partition as /. No swap; a page will come up saying you didn't make a swap partition, but just ignore it.
4. These instructions also work on Ubuntu and other *buntu distributions that also use the ubiquity live CD installer. In Ubuntu the default text editor is gedit instead of leafpad.

Comment: Now that's what I am talking about. A minimal ubuntu distro. How can I have it more minimized than 4.7GB? Maybe disabling swap may help? +1 for your try

Comment: @kamil In my opinion the "best results" in the screenshot means two things _stability_ and _performance_. The lightweight varieties of Ubuntu are not as user friendly as Ubuntu so you have to fall back and use the terminal more. That's OK if you don't mind using the terminal. However if you run short on the system requirements, you may have stability and performance issues. You don't have any drive space for updates or installing software, but you should watch out for these issues in your web browser. Modern web browser are memory hogs, so if you disable swap, it may slow down your browser.

Comment: I know that. I don't want a terminal interface. GUI is a most. I won't need more space because I won't use a browser. All what I need are some remote desktop clients and to burn CD/DVDs

Comment: Boot the Lubuntu live USB. Open a terminal. Type `gksu leafpad /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py` Click on Options and select line number. At about line #853 will be something like "min_disk size = size x 2 #fudge factor", change 2 to 1.4 then save and run the Install Lubuntu. It should now say minimum disk size 3GB. Just be sure when you get to the disk partition/install part select Other and set up the drive as one ext4 partition as /. No swap; a page will come up saying you didn't make a swap partition, but just ignore it. [thecure](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1787628.html)

Comment: You are awesome! I will try it and get back tomorrow to post my result here. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want Ubuntu installed and not any one of these [Small Linux Distros](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552), you can install it to a USB Flash Drive or USB External Hard Drive. I have a USB Flash Drive that is 64GB and it barley sticks out of my computer. ([64 GB Flash Drive on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FJRS6QY))

Comment: this is not an option for my company

Comment: @kamil Well then it is pretty darn hard you need to shrink the other partitions such as the Windows C:/ drive.

Comment: what about @karel answer? using lubuntu !

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several options. Personally I love crunchbang.

[8 small linux distros](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552)

Comment: Just thought I'd ask, are you trying to dual-boot? Does the machine already have an OS and there is only 3.5GB left? Because now that I'm thinking about it, that would be a pretty small partition. You could probably install the OS, but not much else added onto it.

Comment: it will be the only OS. I am using a mini pc to behave like dump terminal workstation for remote desktop using freenx and x2go and xrdp

Comment: your options are not ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Mini Remix is a fully working Ubuntu install containing only the minimal set of software to make the system work. Ubuntu Mini Remix install is around 200MB.
http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org

Hope this helps :) - @billy_hendry

Comment: this is not user friendly like Lubuntu and is a terminal interface Ubuntu operating system. but this is the smallest you can get in the way of Ubuntu