# You need at least 8.5GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 4.0GB?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to re-install Ubuntu as it just isn't loading up well at all. However, I am getting this error:

> You need at least 8.5GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 4.0GB!?

- How can I partition the hard drive to make this work?!

[image: This Picture]

Update: I opened `GParted` to start partitioning my hard drive but this was my only option.

[image: Partitioning]

I have a `terrabyte` on this computer, why aren't the other ones showing up?

I was advised to go into terminal and to type DF. You can see the results below:

[Typing DF in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIoEn.png)

Just to confirm that it isn't recognizing my sda:

[only sdb showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Y7D.png)

Comment: Please don't link to external image sites. The link will die eventually, making your question useless.  Just put the error text into the question.

Comment: Linking to images is OK if it adds context to see the screenshot.

Comment: @karel You believe that's the case here?

Comment: Yes, I think the screenshot is OK here because it adds context by showing which screen of the Ubuntu installer showed the error.

Comment: @karel The error being "How can I partition the hard drive to make this work?!" ?  Unlikely, so what's the error?  Is it the text in the question title? Unlikely; no-one's going to ask why they can't install an 8.5gb OS on a 4gb disk, are they?

Comment: It's not unheard of. I answered a similar question: [can I install ubuntu in a 3.5 GB mini pc](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395932/can-i-install-ubuntu-in-a-3-5-gb-mini-pc/396417#396417). I became interested in this question because it has similarities with the other question.

Comment: The picture Partitioning shows partitions of CD, we need to know sizes of partitions on /dev/sda disk

Comment: Your second image shows the partitioning of the DVD drive with your Ubuntu DVD in it.  You can't install there.  Get us the information for the hard disk, you'll probably find there's plenty of free space on that.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. the /sda isn't showing up when I click on the top right to find alternatives.

Comment: the only option that is there is /dev/sdb

Comment: almost like my computer isn't recognizing the /sda whatsoever.

Comment: What shows when you type to terminal `df`?

Comment: I edited my post. Sorry I don't think I am allowed to post it as a picture without a link.

Comment: You say you're trying to RE-INSTALL Ubuntu - so you had it installed previously? Are you dual booting? Have you got backups of your personal data? You could try the "Erase entire disk and install" option from the installer.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of terminal output. Copy-paste the text, and use `<pre></pre>` tags to make the formatting work.

Comment: @wjandrea The [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) are easier to use.

Comment: You can try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328719
It ansver helps me.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Please change your partition table, the terabyte of diskspace is not selected. The drive you have choose for installation is a flash drive(usb), here your have to chose Your hdd which will be like:  `/dev/sda`
Have a look again and select right drive.

Comment: But that is the only option available from the selection at the top right.

Comment: It isn't recognizing my SDA whatsoever.

Comment: But have a look at my updated post with the picture from the terminal.

Comment: before installation check bios whether you hdd is detect or not.

Comment: @anand How would it boot if the disk is not detected?

Comment: because I am booting from USB

Comment: I have added one more picture to prove.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that it can boot but with some problems. So then it can be disk failture. I saw computer where disk randomly caused errors, so I changed it, but today it's running again as new because it was sata cable failture. What I want to say, if disk behaves strange, it doesn't always mean that the disk is bad.

Comment: @Benjamints have you solved the problem, if done than mark best answer or explain your solution so that this question help others