# How do I Install Ubuntu, Xubuntu or Lubuntu on a 7.2GB USB stick

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, usb-drive

Xubuntu 19.04 and Lubuntu 19.04 (smaller distros) says:
"There is not enough drive space. At least 8 GB is required"

Is there a previous version of any of those distros that can work with the USB space I have?

Thanks.

1) Someone said my question may already have an answer here:
[Can I install Ubuntu on a 3.5GB mini PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395932/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-3-5gb-mini-pc)

That answer was written in 2013. It refers to Lubuntu 13.10 which is rather old. Better answers with more recent versions should be available and tested nowadays. Thank you.

[The accepted answer to that question was updated to 2019 Ubuntu versions before you posted the edit before this one. I suggest that you take some time to read it, specifically list item 4] <-- I didn-t write this. I reviewed the post above and there's nothing there written in 2019.

2) Someone said my question may already have an answer here: 
[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Nothing to do with my problem about the USB space I have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Ubuntu on a 3.5GB mini PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395932/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-3-5gb-mini-pc) and [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/)

Comment: As a workaround you can use Ubuntu Mini CD and install it. After that just run the USB and install whatever desktop and apps you like. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Xubuntu and Lubuntu are generally seen as 'lighter' releases of Ubuntu, lighter in relationship to the amount of resources (cpu, memory..) required to run them, not smaller footprint.  Ubuntu server or minimal install will be the smallest, then add whatever you want/need.

Comment: If you are stuck making a Full install to 8GB USB then there is not much wrong with a Persistent install. About 2GB is used for the OS leaving the rest for persistence. see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168877/is-there-any-problem-with-a-full-installation-on-a-usb-drive/1168922#1168922  **Mkusb** is the best Persistent USB maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A USB stick with 8 GB (nominally) will often contain slightly less drive space, but your 7.2 value is probably the size in GiB (gibibytes with base 2)

```
7.2*2^30/10^9=7.73 conversion to GB (gigabytes)
```

and it is too small anyway to install the current version of Ubuntu.

**If you want a good installed system, you should get a [fast USB 3 stick with at least 16 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size).**

With an 8 GB stick I would recommend

1. A [persistent live drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent). This should work well.
2. The already suggested workaround via the Ubuntu [mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). This should work, but very soon you will find that the drive space will be too small.

Comment: I accept that I can't do what I wanted.

From the suggestions above, I tried Ubuntu server 19.04. Installation didn't fit in 7.2GB. I had some problems finding the mini.iso Iso file, and then I read "very soon you will find that the drive space will be too small", so I didn't try that. Thanks to everyone for the help. 

I keep on using Puppy Linux (xenialpup)... I just wanted to have something closer to Ubuntu with complete use of bash commands and where I can create a wifi hot-spot.

Comment: @ShirleyTemple, Have a try with a persistent live Lubuntu system in your 8 GB stick, or get a fast 16 GB USB3 stick and install what you really want. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) may help.